# Model checking tool c#

Tags: c#, model-checking

Is there any model checking library for c# code?
I am seeking for pre,post condition annotations class invariants, like in Eiffel. 
I have googled [Spec#](http://specsharp.codeplex.com/) but as I understood it is language extension not a library as I would expect.

Thank You!

Comment: Have you looked at [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx)?

Comment: Thank You!!! Could you please submit it as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx).